# Read PDF File in Java - No External Libraries

Tags: java, pdf, file-io

I've been writing a simple Java server over the last few weeks.

First I wanted to display the the filesystem based on where you started the server.  For example, if you started the server in the `src` directory, opened up a browser, and went to localhost:5555 you would see the files and directories contained in `src`.  Each would be linked.  And I got that working fine.

If you click a directory, it shows you its contents (just like I mentioned).  If you click a file, it reads the file and displays that file in plain text.  If you click an image, it serves that image.  This all happens in the browser and you can use the back button to return to the directory listings or file you were previously viewing.  This also works fine and uses no external libraries.

This is the code I'm using to read a text file (using a reader):

```
private String readFile() {
    BufferedReader reader;
    String response = "";
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(requestedFile);
        reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line + "\n";
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

This is the code I'm using to serve images (an input stream instead of a reader):

```
public byte[] getByteArray() throws IOException {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) requestedFile.length()];
    InputStream inputStream;
    String fileName = String.valueOf(requestedFile);
    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while (bytesRead < byteArray.length) {
        int bytesRemaining = byteArray.length - bytesRead;
        int read = inputStream.read(byteArray, bytesRead, bytesRemaining);
        if (read > 0) {
            bytesRead += read;
        }
    }
    inputStream.close();
    FilterOutputStream binaryOutputStream = new FilterOutputStream(outputStream);
    byte [] binaryHeaders = headers.getBytes();
    byte [] fullBinaryResponse = new byte[binaryHeaders.length + byteArray.length];
    System.arraycopy(binaryHeaders, 0, fullBinaryResponse, 0, binaryHeaders.length);
    System.arraycopy(byteArray, 0, fullBinaryResponse, binaryHeaders.length, byteArray.length);
    try {
        binaryOutputStream.write(fullBinaryResponse);
        binaryOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting now is to serve PDFs.  If I have a PDF in one of the directories and I click it, it should open that PDF (in whatever default reader the browser uses).

I've been Googling this topic and trying out a few things for a day or two and I can't seem to get it.  I find it strange that when I click on the PDF as my code currently is, the browser seems like it's opening the PDF but no text appears.  It's the standard in-browser PDF viewer that we're all used to seeing when we click a PDF link.  But there's no content.  It's just some blank pages.

Can anyone help with this?  I'm not going to use an external library.  I just want to understand how to open the PDF file in Java.

Thanks!

Comment: Just open the file and stream it back; what's the issue? Without knowing what you're actually doing, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Are you saying it can be read exactly as I'm reading a text file (like above)?

Comment: PDF files are binary files, not text files, so you cannot mess with its content (like adding  "\n") or read it line by line, since there is no concept of text lines there.

Comment: Neither is there something like a common character encoding. By using a ...Reader you implicitly assume  there is. I'm actually surprised you can serve images with your method. And furthermore, what if the files are some gigabytes in size, do you want to read them like you do in your code before serving them?

Comment: No, this isn't the code I'm using to serve images. The code above is just for text files. I'm using an InputStream to read images.

Comment: You should show the code you're actually using, then: as others have said, PDF != text; you should stream back the bytes it contains, nothing more.

Comment: as here said I would be very surprised if u could just read a PDF file like a text file... why not using an external library...

Comment: I don't have code that will read a PDF. That's where my question is coming from. I have code (above) that I'm using to read a text file. I was curious about how to read a PDF. Apparently that requires using an InputStream (as I did when reading images).

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse it as text, which will convert characters, possibly end lines, and might change things you don't desire.  Don't buffer the whole thing as an array of bytes, but instead write directly to the output stream so there are no memory issues.  Instead, just serve the file up like this:

```
public class FileServer extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
    OutputStream out=null;
    try {

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        out = resp.getOutputStream();
        resp.setContentType(-- specify content type here --);
        req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String pathInfo = req.getPathInfo();

        String fullPath = -- figure out the path to the file in question --;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fullPath);

        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];

        int amtRead = fis.read(buf);
        while (amtRead > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, amtRead);
            amtRead = fis.read(buf);
        }
        fis.close();
        out.flush();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            if (out == null) {
                out = resp.getOutputStream();
            }
            Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
            w.write("<html><body><ul><li>Exception: ");
            w.write(e.toString());
            w.write("</ul></body></html>");
            w.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception eeeee) {
            //nothing we can do here...
        }
    }
}
}
```